# How to run a Python file from a Batch File with Anaconda prompt on Windows 10?

Tags: python, batch-file, windows-10

I created a script in python and I need it to run in way that the python code is not visible. I tried different methods like implementing nodeJS and PHP, but to no avail. So, I thought of using a .bat file to run the python file. I created a bat file for the python script, but on clicking the batch file all I got was an error saying that a module was missing in the code. The code works perfectly when I run it in Spyder and on the Anaconda Prompt. So, I thought of running the file from a batch file via the Anaconda Prompt. The code in the batch file is below:

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe /K ""C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3""
python myscript.py
pause
```

The .bat file now opens a command prompt in the python environment, but does not run the python file. I tried altering the code, but it was always the same result. If I type:

```
python myscript.py
```

into the next line in the command prompt, the python file gets executed. I need to find a way for the file to be executed without typing anything in the prompt. The python file contains GUI from tkinter and the shebang line has the python version (3.7.4). I work with Windows 10.

I tried this code in the batch file as well,

```
"C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Users\Sathya\Desktop\myscript.py"
pause
```

All this did was open and close the command prompt in the blink of an eye. I tried to run the bat file a few more times, but got the same result. But, this code worked on a different file (also with tkinter GUI) `myscript_test.py` and this one gave the GUI window correctly. I don't have a clue as to why it worked on the second one and not the first one.

Comment: What happens if you just `Call` `… activate.bat …` instead of trying to run it within its own isolated instance of `cmd.exe`?

Comment: @Compo when I tried that, it gave an error stating `C:\Program` is not a recognized command and went ahead to open the python file in notepad. But in the isolated instance of `cmd.exe` only the anaconda prompt is opened. Once I type in `myscript.py` into the command line, the GUI window pops up. When I use the `python.exe` option to open the file, the command prompt opens and closes in the blink of an eye, but does not run the python file. I even tried it with `pythonw.exe`

Comment: A way to solve it would be to execute the commands in the batch file sequentially, but I have no idea how to do so. As of now, it just executes the first line to create the python environment and ignores everything else.

Comment: Well "'C:\Program' is not a recognized …"` indicates only a quoting issue, not an issue with my advice to use `Call`. If you didn't quote your `Call` command then do so, if you did then the issue is with how `activate bat` deals with a quoted argument. `Call "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3"`, `"C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Users\Sathya\Desktop\myscript.py"`, `Pause`

Comment: @Compo Thanks a lot!! It worked and the GUI window opened. I had been trying different variations for it for the past few days. Thanks a ton.